# best way to store in database laravel relations hasmany

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have two models, User and Docente. These are your relationships

**User.php**

```
public function docente()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Docente::class);
}
```

**Docente.php**

```
public function usuario()
{
   return $this->hasOne(User::class,'id','user_id');
}
```

To insert a new record, first enter the users table and then that id sent it to the Docente model *(table docentes)*  to do the insertion.

```
public function store(DocenteRequest $request)
{

    $newUser = (new User)->fill($request->only('nivel_id','username','password'));
    $newUser->nivel_id = 2; // fixed
    $newUser->save();

    $newDocente = (new Docente)
                ->fill($request->only('dni','especialidad','sexo','apellido_paterno','apellido_materno','nombre','telefono','direccion','comentario'));
    $newDocente->user_id = $newUser->id;
    $newDocente->save();

    return redirect()->route('docente.index');
}
```

It works but I would like to know if there is a more optimal, advisable and perhaps elegant way to do this.

**Edit**

**DocenteRequest**

```
    return [
                'dni' => 'required|digits:8|numeric|unique:docentes,dni',
                'especialidad' => 'required|min:3|max:60',
                'sexo' => 'required|not_in:0',
                'apellido_paterno' => 'required|min:2|max:80',
                'apellido_materno' => 'required|min:2|max:80',
                'nombre' => 'required|min:2|max:80',
                'telefono' => 'required|min:6|max:11',
                'direccion' => 'required|string',
                'username'=>'required|max:100|unique:users',
                'password' => 'required|min:7|max:200',

            ];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already use mass assignment, use the `create()` method:

```
public function store(DocenteRequest $request)
{
    $user = User::create($request->except('nivel_id') + ['nivel_id' => 2]);
    $user->docente()->create($request->all());
    return redirect()->route('docente.index');
}
```

You don't need to use `only()` because of mass assignment, you can just pass all the data which will be filtered.

Also, the `usuario` relation should be `belongsTo()`:

```
public function usuario()
{
   return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

Comment: I tested your code and it works to a certain extent, since null is registered in the user_id field of the docentes table

Comment: @DarkFenix I'm pretty sure the code is correct and `user_id` must be automatically filled if you didn't modify the code. Please try to copy and paste my code and use it without modifications.

Comment: Would you be so kind as to tell me what the correct eloquent relationship would be like? Maybe that's why he's failing. Taking into consideration that a user can belong only 1 Docente.

Comment: @DarkFenix the `docente()` relationship looks fine if you have `user_id` in the `docentes` table.

Comment: Yes, if it exists in the docentes ' table. that's why I'm surprised a bit because he leaves the field null

Comment: @DarkFenix do you have `user_id` in the `Request` object or something? I've just tried to use the same code with `hasOne()` relationship and it works perfectly.

Comment: no, as I did not enter it for the form, I thought it necessary not to add it. Is it necessary to do it? . You can update your answer with this point. I updated my question

Comment: @DarkFenix no you don't need to add it to the form. I just thought maybe you did it before. Are you sure you're using my code without any modifications?

Answer (score 1):

edit the relationship, it should be a belongsTo

```
public function docente()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

then in controller for adding new `docente` for existing  `user`

```
$user->docente()->save($newDocente);
```

Comment: How would the complete code for the controller be? First I must add the User and then the Docente.

Comment: Yes, first save user, but you don't need to set user_id on  newDocente  , just save it on $user instance

Comment: Is the maximum you can optimize the registration process? I read about assync and attach

Comment: `sync` and `attach` are for many-to-many relationships, I this your relationship is one-to-many